# The eigenvalues of a specific Kronecker sum

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product

I am interested in the eigenvalues of the matrix $J = B \otimes A + M \otimes I_n$ where $A$ is $n \times n$, binary and symmetric (it is an adjacency matrix), $B$ is $m \times m$ diagonal with positive entries, $M$ is $m \times m$ with negative entries on the diagonal and positive entries on the off-diagonal.

This is similar looking to the Kronecker sum of two matrices
\begin{equation}
A \oplus B = I_m \otimes A + B \otimes I_n
\end{equation}
The Kronecker sum has the property that it's eigenvalues are the pairwise sums of the spectrums of $A$ and $B$. More precisely, for $\lambda_i \in \text{spectrum } A$, $i = 1, ..., n$, and $\mu_j \in \text{spectrum }B$, $j = 1, \ldots, m$, $A \oplus B$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i + \mu_j$ $i = 1, \ldots, n$, $j = 1, \ldots, m$. Moreover, if $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are right eigenvectors of $A$ and $z_1, \ldots, z_m$ are right eigenvectors of $B$, then $z_j \otimes x_i$ are the right eigenvectors of $A \oplus B$ corresponding to $\lambda_i + \mu_j$.

Is it possible to derive similar properties of the eigenvalues of $J$? I have tried the following: assume $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $z$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\mu$. The eigenvalues of $J$ have the form

\begin{align}
J (z \otimes x) & = (B \otimes A + M \otimes I_n)(z \otimes x) \newline
& = (B \otimes A)(z \otimes x) + (M \otimes I_n)(z \otimes x) \newline
& = Bz \otimes Ax + Mz \otimes x \newline
& = Bz \otimes \lambda x + \mu z \otimes x \newline
& = \lambda(Bz \otimes x) + \mu(z \otimes x)
\end{align}
And here I am stuck. Am I wrong from the very beginning? If $B = I_m$ we have the result for the Kronecker sum. If $B = \text{diag}(b, \ldots, b)$, then $b\lambda + \mu$ is the eigenvalue of the eigenvector $z \otimes x$.

I have also thought of pursuing the generalized eigenvalue problem, and the eigenvalue perturbation theory route.

Comment: You get a nice result when $M$ and $B$ commute, but in general

Comment: I'm sorry did you mean a result is not possible in general? I cannot even provide bounds? Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "but **not** in general. In other words, the eigenvalues of $A \otimes B + M \otimes I$ cannot be deduced using only the eigenvalues of $A,B,$ and $M$. You could certainly provide some kinds of bounds using the general techniques that apply to symmetric matrices, but I don't see a good way to take advantage of the particular structure present here.

Comment: If you're interested in the sign of the eigenvalues, then it is helpful to note that
$$
(B^{-1/2} \otimes I)J(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) = A \oplus (B^{-1/2}MB^{-1/2})
$$
is a symmetric matrix with the same signature

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. Could you share a reference for the result?

Comment: Do you mean my last result?  I don't have reference that says exactly what I've said, but I could write an answer explaining my comment in further detail if you're interested

Comment: If it wont take much of your time then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) J (B^{-1/2} \otimes I)$ is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $J$, so that its signature is identical to that of $J$. We compute
$$
(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) J (B^{-1/2} \otimes I) 
\\= 
(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) (B \otimes A + M \otimes I) (B^{-1/2} \otimes I)
\\ = 
(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) (B \otimes A) (B^{-1/2} \otimes I)
+
(B^{-1/2} \otimes I) (M \otimes I) (B^{-1/2} \otimes I)
\\ = 
(B^{-1/2}BB^{-1/2}) \otimes A + (B^{-1/2}MB^{-1/2} \otimes I)\\
= I \otimes A + (B^{-1/2}MB^{-1/2} \otimes I)\\
= A \oplus (B^{-1/2}MB^{-1/2}).
$$
Note also that $B^{-1/2}MB^{-1/2}$ has the same signature as $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much.